# Tkinter - How to understand when the cursor is placed over a text widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I would very like to do something when the mouse cursor is placed over a TK Text widget (without clicking). How can I get this event?

Comment: You can bind `<Enter>` event on the text widget.

Comment: @acw1668: thanks! to make it easier understanding for the other users, I solved using the "bind" method as advised by acw1668. example: TEXT WIDGET.bind("<Enter>", CUSTOM FUNCTION)

Comment: @acw1668: just a question. what is the opposite event to <Enter>? I mean, how can I bind the event when the cursor is not placed over the text widget anymore?

Comment: It is `<Leave>` event.

Comment: @acw1668: thanks! my software starts to be really cool now ahah..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tkinter fires the `<Enter>` event with the cursor enters a widget, and `<Leave>` when it leaves.

```
import tkinter as tk

def handle_enter(event):
    event.widget.insert("end", "Cursor has entered the chat\n")

def handle_leave(event):
    event.widget.insert("end", "Cursor has left the chat\n")

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.bind("<Enter>", handle_enter)
text.bind("<Leave>", handle_leave)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -3):

Try the following code. It is a quick snippet:

```
#Import the tkinter library
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.tix import *

#Create an instance of tkinter frame
win = Tk()
#Set the geometry
win.geometry("400x200")

#Create a tooltip
tip= Balloon(win)

#Create a Button widget
my_button=Button(win, text= "Python", font=('Poppins', 20))
my_button.pack(pady=20)

#Bind the tooltip with button
tip.bind_widget(my_button,balloonmsg="Python is an interpreted, high-level
and general-purpose programming language")

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: If any questions, Tag me.

Comment: Hi bro, thanks for your reply but it was not what I wanted to do. acw1668 replied correctly to my question. I replied to him too.

Comment: `tix` is a deprecated module.